# Get namespace in a static function

Tags: .net, namespaces, static-methods

In an instance method, I can easily find the executing namespace:

```
public void PrintNamespace()
{
  Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().Namespace);
}
```

Q: How do I do the same in a **static** function (no *this* available) without explicitely mentioning the class name? (no `typeof(MyClass)` )

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(TheClassThatContainsTheStaticFunction).Namespace);
```

Or using reflection:

```
Console.WriteLine(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Namespace);
```

Comment: Ah yes, I should have been more explicit about not wanting the first solution. The 2nd one is what I was looking for. Thanks!