# Print the namespace of the currently executing code in C# running in .NET 7

Tags: c#, console, system.reflection

I'd like to print the namespace of the currently executing code running in .NET 7 using C#.

Something akin to:

Inside of Main (in Program.cs of a program called myApp):

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine(ns);
```

expected output:
myApp

...the namespace of the program.

by way of background, prior to .NET 6, a program like myApp would look like this:

```
using System;

namespace myApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

In order to better understand what's going on, I'm trying to determine where my code lives using reflection (indeed I read [Top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements) on the Microsoft site, but I'm interested in that "an implementation detail that your code can't reference directly").

Comment: Current Context is something different then the calling(hosting) assembly to me. And the namespace of that something totally different to me. When the process host isn't managed code but something else GetEntryAssembly will be null.

Comment: What is "current context" here?

Comment: @KlausGütter - edited question to clarify and removed assembly code per Ralf's point.

Comment: Namespaces only exist to allow you to fully qualify a Type. What Type holds the code that is being executed? If you know that, the Type's `GetType()` info has what you're looking for.

Comment: Still don't know what you mean by "current context". The currently executing method? The class where it is defined? The thread or task? Synchronization context?

Comment: @KlausGütter - I clarified the question and edited to suit - I have created a new .NET 7 console application and want to print the namespace where main resides (as an example)

Comment: The question does not show [MRE] if it is debugging question ("why my code does not work"), no indication that you know how to obtain that information without using top-level statements, and no indication that you know that namespace can be empty... We already have plenty of questions about "how to get information about current method with reflection", so I picked some as duplicates. If you actually have question why *your* code doesn't work - make sure to [edit] the question to show all code necessary to investigate.

Comment: it's not a duplicate - the other question is about the name of the executing method, not the namespace - do some homework!

Comment: @decuser future SO visitors (who we actually provide the answers for) should be considered reasonable aware of the language/frameworks features and in this particular case should be easily figure out how to get namespace of a type if they have a type (as shown in one of the linked duplicates). Your suggestion that they would not be able to get that one they own feels a bit rude... but for those folks I've added another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831480/get-namespace-in-a-static-function) that shows all calls.

Comment: @decuser I removed code that looks like request for debugging help and added your research. I still believe that the information you/future visitors  are looking for is already on the site in linked duplicates. If that is not the case please [edit] the post to clarify what is missing.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - clearly, I'm missing something. The code: MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Namespace is empty in an otherwise empty .NET 7 program. Works fine in .NET 3.1. Is the main method in .NET 7 not in a namespace?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249966/discussion-between-decuser-and-alexei-levenkov).

Comment: You've missed my previous comment "and no indication that you know that namespace can be empty...".

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var ns = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()?.DeclaringType?.Namespace ?? string.Empty;
Console.WriteLine(ns);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.  Do note, if you remove the namespace from the entry point it will return null (just tested that in a Console app).

```
var entry = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.EntryPoint?.DeclaringType?.Namespace ?? "(null)";
Console.WriteLine(entry);
```

Comment: Seems to result in null in isolated .NET 7 Azure Functions.